# How to change optimization of all caller function when an inline function is called?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a Makefile project to compile bunch of C files. All the files in the project are compiled with optimization level zero but certain functions require optimization level 2 (O2). All those functions which require optimization level 2 are always using a static inline function from a header file.

My requirement is whenever a function uses this inline function from header file, should change its optimization level from O0 to O2 automatically. Is there any provision in GCC which accomplish this requirement?

I have tried changing optimization level of each function which uses the inline function by adding GCC attribute, `__attribute__((optimize("O2")))` and it works well. But this inline function is used in more than 200 locations in my project and I have to change the optimization of the function using above strategy in more than 200 locations which is not looking good solution for me

```
include "foo.h"

void abc ()
{
 ....
}

void __attribute__((optimize("O2"))) foo()
{
 ...
 "uses inline function from foo.h"
}
```

`abc` compiles with optimization 0 from GCC command line.
Need `foo()` to compile with optimization O2 without GCC attribute option.
I also tried adding GCC attribute to the actual inline function but it does not affect foo's optimization.

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)!

Comment: I think you are having a different problem, rather than the optimisation one. If you need to do this trick due to lack of speed, then you should consider changing the algorithm you are using. Otherwise, please, add more information and context on why you need to optimise like this. Finally, the optimisation level is usually set globally per build, it depends on the build type (DEBUG or RELEASE). Sure, you can add attributes or pragmas to modify it, but is something you should normally want to avoid.

Comment: @linuxpro if you need `my_inline_fn` to be optimised, just add the `__attribute__` to this function, instead of adding it to `foo`. Otherwise, you are optimising the entire `foo` function, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @linuxpro anyway, your comment does not add more information nor context to your question. You are just writing the inlined function you have, not `why` you need to optimise it. `why` you need to do this is what really matters, since probably you are overthinking the problem or looking into the wrong solution.

Comment: @LopiTal I could find code similar to my inline function in linux source code, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/cmpxchg.h#L28
similar to this header file, my switch case are having assembly instructions and requires caller function compiled with optimization O2. When the caller is not compiled with O2, then program is not working as expected. The inline function requires the caller to be compiled in O2. Is there any option in gcc which forces caller to O2 by adding special flags to inline function.

Comment: ok, now this is different. Since now we have more context, we can help you a bit more. My `guess` is that the problem is not with the optimisation itself, but with the ASM expecting some registers to have the correct data, and, just lucky enough, this happens when optimising to -O2. You should add your ASM code and your comment to the question, and probably modify the title to pinpoint this. Then somebody can help you a bit more with your actual problem. Unfortunately, I cannot help you with ASM, since I am no expert on it.